# Checking if json key exists for a given array index?

Tags: c#, json

This code throws an exception if the key does not exist.

For example, if the key exists for a position in an array index the code is okay, even if the value is `null`. But, if the key does not exist the code throws an exception`. The code in the select token parenthesis is dynamic (a string variable).

```
r["Value"] = json.SelectToken($.Objectives[x].state).ToString() ?? "";
```

Comment: I'm assuming $.Objectives[x].state is what is throwing an exception?  What did you want it to do instead?

Comment: Dave, yes. The code is in a loop, and works fine until the key is actually missing, it then throws an exception

Comment: is X a number or a string... you keep saying "key" which makes me think it is a string.  that is are you going after an index or a property?

Comment: x is the integer representing the index of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call ToString() on a null value.

```
JToken value = json.SelectToken("$.Objectives[x].state");
r["Value"] = (value != null) ? value.ToString() : "";
```

Comment: Hi Have never seen this syntax before. What does (value != null)  do?

Comment: To put it simply, it checks whether or not the object exists.  If you want to know more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tenary operator to return a default value if x doesn't exist

```
r["Value"] = $.Objectives[x] ? 
    json.SelectToken($.Objectives[x].state).ToString() ?? " 
    : '';
```

OR

```
r["Value"] = x >= $.Objectives.Length ? 
    json.SelectToken($.Objectives[x].state).ToString() ?? " 
    : '';
```

I'm not sure why you end the line with a double quote.  Maybe a typo?  But I didn't fix it, that code is what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if a given variable has a value, it will return `true` to the following:

```
if(r["Value"]){
   //this only runs if r["Value"] exists
}
```